# how to convert csv date format from yyyy/mm/ddd to yyyymmdd

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am trying to import a csv with a date in the following format:
        `2018/01/25`
the date format in mysql is in Int and I want to remove the slashes in the current date format.
I need to get the date looking like this:

```
20180125
```

I need to work only on the first column and not the rest of the csv.
here is the code for reading the csv.

```
while(reader.readLine()!= null)
{

    String read = reader.readLine();//bufferedreader string variable
    String [] rawRow = read.split(",");
    String lastEntry = rawRow[rawRow.length-1];// this contains MemberNo/branchNo
    String [] properLastEntry = lastEntry.split("/");//this contains MemberNo,BranchNo
    //memory that contains rawRow nd properLastEntry in a single array
    String [] oneRow = new String[rawRow.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(rawRow, 0, oneRow, 0,rawRow.length-1);
    System.arraycopy(properLastEntry, 0, oneRow, oneRow.length - properLastEntry.length,properLastEntry.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneRow));

    rs2.add(oneRow);    
}
```

Comment: You must be very certain that there are no quoted or escaped commas ever allowed in that CSV, or that `split` call will give you wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it come from the database in a `java.sql.Date` object?

Well, if you're reading it as a string, just do this:

```
String convert(String dateIn) {
    String year = dateIn.subString(0,4);
    String month = dateIn.subString(5,7);
    String day = dateIn.subString(8);
    return year + month + day;
}
```

Of course it's still a very bad idea to read the date as a String from the database, because the format is not guaranteed to be the same on every server. Could be one on your test server and another on the production.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * 
 * @author CHIRAG
 *
 */
public class DateConverter {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String date = "2018/01/25";
        System.out.println(date + " converted to -> " + convertDate(date));
    }

    public static String convertDate(String date) {
        return date.replaceAll("/|-", ""); // it will remove all occurrences of '/' or '-'
    }
}
```

The output of this code snip is:

```
2018/01/25 converted to -> 20180125
```

Only you have to pass `date string` to the method `convertDate(String date)`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.